# How to use Microsoft.Extensions.Logging in a .NET Core 3.0 Worker Service

Tags: logging, .net-core, nlog, .net-core-3.0

I started a new Windows service project and decided to use the .NET Core 3.0 Worker Service template. This service will never be used in a cloud/web project, but there's a chance I might want to adapt it to run on Linux at some point.

I'm very familiar with the use of NLog for logging. The model of creating a new static logger object within every class is very intuitive. I see that the Worker Service has the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` framework baked in, to the point that the default worker has an `ILogger<Worker>` passed right in. That's great for "my first service", but what about a real long-running service with lots of classes, each requiring logging?

All the tutorials I find for this template deal with services which do all the work and logging in the Worker class. For historical reasons, most logging articles consider only ASP.NET core, in which DI is a priority. I have not found any description of how to build an app with a tree of multiple long-lived classes, each of which has its own `ILogger` object to write to.

Even though I will never need DI in this project, it seems like it might be a good standard to adopt across my code base, initially hooking it up to the NLog provider. I could grab the `IHostBuilder` in my `Main`, then as add a static function to create loggers from its `ILoggingBuilder` in a similar way to NLog, but I can't believe that's the best way.

Is there an established best practice here? Does it involve unpicking some of the magic from the Worker Service template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NLog works fine in .Net Core without any help from dependency injection. You just do like always:

```
private static readonly NLog.Logger Logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

private static void Main()
{
    Logger.Info("Hello World");
}
```

But NLog can also integrate with Microsoft Extension Logging (MEL) using Microsoft Dependency Injection. You just have to register the [NLog LoggingProvider](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extensions.Logging) and then MEL-ILogger input will be forwarded to NLog.

In `IHostBuilder.ConfigureLogging` then one can call `AddNLog()` (Just like one can call `AddDebug()` or `AddConsole()` for the builtin MEL-LoggingProviders)

You can find a simple example of this on the wiki-page (Also has a link to ASP.NET Core if needed):

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-.NET-Core-2---Console-application

Some people don't like that the MEL-ILogger has to be injected through the class-constructor for even simple classes (too much clutter). Instead they just use `NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()` directly.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying, "no, MEL-ILogger really is that as clunky as you feared. There is no nice way for desktop apps." If true, I appreciate your saving me the time of exploring any further! Having to create all the loggers in one place then feed them down to each constructor is really too much cruft for a complex app. Not to mention deserializing an object model like that. The followup question would be how best to remove MEL from the Worker project if I don't want it.

Comment: Well ilogger-injection into the constructor happens automatically by the dependency injection framework. Microsoft uses the MEL-ILogger inside their NetCore-framework, so if wanting their logging-output for troubleshooting, then you should just leave it be. But it sounds like a whole new question.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's worth having a look at `Serilog` https://serilog.net/?
Serilog is very flexible, and you may add a variaty of sinks, e.g: console, file, elasticsearch, seq, others.. And you don't have to DI it all over the place.

This is how I use it to print to the console (std::out).

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Serilog;
namespace YourNamespace
{
public class Program
{
    private static readonly string _applicationName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name;
    public static IConfiguration Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
              .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
              .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
              .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}.json", reloadOnChange: true, optional: true)
              .AddEnvironmentVariables()
              .Build();

    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        // serilog
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                        .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
                        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                        .CreateLogger();

        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")))
                throw new Exception("Hosting environment variable not set");

            Log.Information($"Bootstrapping application: {_applicationName}");
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            Log.Information($"Gracefully closing application: {_applicationName}");
            return 0; // returning a zero, indicates a successful shutdown.
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Information($"Host {_applicationName} - terminated unexpectedly.", e);
            return 1; // returning a none-zero, indicates failure.
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseConfiguration(Configuration)
            .UseSerilog(); // overrides default logger
}
}
```

And you may now use it wherever you want to in your program, e.g a Controller

```cs
try 
{
   Log.Information("Testing the logs..");
}
catch (Exception e)
{      
   Log.Error("{@e}", e); // stack trace or other objects where {@e} is the object template.
   return BadRequest($"Rule violation: {e.Message}");
}
```

And the corresponding configuration (only writes to console):

```js
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": { // overrides default logger from MS
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },  
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj} {SourceContext}>{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

And the nugets:

```xml
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="3.1.1" />
```

If you do want to DI loggers, maybe you should have a look at Autofac DI framwork?
Hopefully it helps.